# Seeking method for validating existence of a contract across EVM compatible chains?

Tags: evm, cross-chain

We have a function that checks existence of a contract address as follows:

```
function _assertContractSupportsERC721Interface(address _contract)
        private
        view
    {
        try IERC721(_contract).supportsInterface(_INTERFACE_ID_ERC721) returns (
            bool mainResult
        ) {
            // We might be dealing with the CryptoKitties contract if result is false
            if (mainResult == false) {
                try
                    IERC721(_contract).supportsInterface(
                        _INTERFACE_ID_ERC721_CryptoKitties
                    )
                returns (bool result) {
                    require(
                        result == true,
                        "Contract does not implement the ERC721 interface"
                    );
                } catch Error(string memory reason) {
                    revert(reason);
                } catch {
                    revert("Invalid NFT contract");
                }
            }
        } catch Error(string memory reason) {
            revert(reason);
        } catch {
            revert("Invalid NFT contract");
        }
    }
```

However it only works when `_contract` is on the same chain as the detecting smart contract. Our use case requires detecting existence across EVM compatible chains.

Is there a feasible solution to this?

Comment: You won't be able to do that directly in a smart contract, since that is running isolated within one chain. To do this on-chain, you would need to use some service which acts as an off-chain bridge which would be able to provide this information to you. It is unlikely that such a service exists in my opinion. It would probably be better to perform this logic off-chain. You could also build your own off-chain bridge so that you can perform this logic on-chain, and if others are interacting with your contract they must trust your bridge.

Comment: That's kind of what I figured, but thought I would ask anyway. Thanks for the confirmation.